# Navigate to a new URL in Javascript with post parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I wanted to know if there was any way to navigate to a new URL using *JavaScript* with POST parameters.

I know with GET you can just append a param string on the URL using `window.location.replace()`

But is there any way to do this using POST to hide the parameters. Or with *jQuery*?

Comment: redirects by nature are GETs.

Comment: You can use ajax to post data and set it in session and on ajax success redirect using location.href

Comment: Only trick you can do is, create a form tag and submit form using `$("form").submit()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. The closest thing you could do is to dynamically create and submit a form, setting its method to POST.

You can always perform a POST request, and then redirect the browser to a new URL via a GET when the post request completes, if you *need* the request to be a POST request.

Your better bet is to use the appropriate HTTP verb, and not use POST requests as a means of "hiding" parameters. POST requests should be used when you're modifying server state, not when you want prettier URLs.

Comment: ok thanks! This url redirect that i want to do comes right after a POST request..so I guess I have no choice but to do so